# Angular 6 primeng p-dataView paginator only generating page 1

Tags: angular, angular6, primeng

So straight to the point, my p-dataView component looks pretty much like the one straight from the primefaces.org tutorial.

```
<p-dataView #dv [value]="routes" [paginator]='true' [rows]="5" totalRecords="{{totalRecords}}" pageLinkSize="3" paginatorPosition="both">
    <p-header>
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            <div class="ui-g">
                <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-4" style="text-align:right">
                    <p-dataViewLayoutOptions></p-dataViewLayoutOptions>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p-header>
    <ng-template let-route pTemplate="listItem">
        <div class="ui-g" style="padding: 2em;border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9">
            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3" style="text-align:center">
                <img [src]="'data:image/png;base64,'+route.thumbnail" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-8 route-details">
                <div class="ui-g">
                    <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Name: </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6"><b>{{route.name}}</b></div>

                    <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Lenght: </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6"><b>{{route.length}}</b></div>

                    <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">RecordTime: </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6"><b>{{route.recordTime}}</b></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-route pTemplate="gridItem">
        <div style="padding:.5em" class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3">
            <p-panel [header]="route.name" [style]="{'text-align':'center'}">
                <div class="route-detail">{{route.length}} - {{route.recordTime}}</div>
                <hr class="ui-widget-content" style="border-top:0">
                <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-search" (click)="selectRoute($event, route)" style="margin-top:0"></button>
            </p-panel>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dataView>
```

and my typescript file

```
@Input('routes') routes: Route[];
@Input('totalRecords') totalRecords: Number;

displayDialog: boolean;

public selectedRoute: Route;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() { }

onDialogHide() {
    this.selectedRoute = null;
}

selectRoute(event: Event, route: Route) {
    this.selectedRoute = route;
    this.displayDialog = true;
    console.log("Selected route: " + this.selectedRoute);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I then use this component elsewhere and I populate the data after I do and API call to the server which then returns data that I populate inside the p-dataView. The paginator is set for true and it displays but it's always page 1. Server returns 10 routes (data) and p-dataView display 5 of them (as set with rows) but the paginator stays only 1 paged. Do I need to implement some kind of logic to do so or is this just some bug? I also dosen't have the look it has on primefaces so it might be something wrong with my project. I created the project using Angular CLI. I also tried to make another project with just p-dataView and paginator still didn't work. This is what it looks like:

[image]

UPDATE:
I call app-routelister (which is my component that has p-dataView) like that with all parameters. "routes" is array of 10 routes and totalRecords is manually set to 100.

```
<div>
  <app-routelister [routes]="routes" [totalRecords]="totalRecords"></app-routelister>
</div>
```

Comment: what does `this.selectedRoute` print in console ? @user3029612

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal "Selected route: [object Object]". This is only used for a differenc view that uses dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I just came accross the same problem. I finally found the solution in the documentation of primeng. Have a look at https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dataview and scroll down to section *Lazy Loading*.

> Lazy mode is handy to deal with large datasets, instead of loading the
>   entire data, small chunks of data is loaded by invoking onLazyLoad
>   callback everytime paging happens. [...] It is also important to
>   assign the logical number of rows to totalRecords by doing a
>   projection query for paginator configuration so that paginator
>   displays the UI assuming there are actually records of totalRecords
>   size although in reality they aren't as in lazy mode, only the records
>   that are displayed on the current page exist.

So regardless of that you are doing real lazy loading or not you have to set the lazy-property to true:

```
<p-dataView #dv [value]="routes" [paginator]="true" [lazy]="true" [rows]="5" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" pageLinkSize="3" paginatorPosition="both">
   <!-- [...] -->
</p-dataView>
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3029612 please make changes in p-dataView and check your totalRecords value and if it's more than 1 it will display your paginator

```
<p-dataView #dv [value]="routes" [paginator]='true' [rows]="5" 
        [totalRecords]="totalRecords" pageLinkSize="3" 
        paginatorPosition="both">
      </p-dataView>
```

Comment: I did those changes my totalRecords is 10 (I did console.log) and I still have only one page

Comment: can you please create a  demo on stackblitz so we can figure out